Cómo Hacer una Solicitud POST en Excel
Tengo una Api que responde con registros de los empleados de una empresa, pero se me solicito que eso mismo se vea en un Excel, la sugerencia fue que podría generarles el archivo, pero no quieren descargar constantemente archivos, entonces se me ocurrió que podría hacer una macros y consumir la petición para poblar el documento.
no tengo mucha experiencia con macros, y en lo que investigo a lo mejor alguien ya hizo algo similar, apreciaría mucho su ayuda!

Puedes enlazar la API con excel: Pestaña datos -> De la web

Podrias modificar el API para que tenga metodos ODATA https://www.odata.org/libraries/

Te mostraré cómo hacerlo utilizando un pequeño código VBA. En este caso, vamos a enviar datos a una API de prueba y procesar la respuesta, voy a explicártelo paso a paso de una manera sencilla.
Primero hay que activar el Editor de VBA: Ve a la pestaña de "Desarrollador" en Excel y selecciona "Visual Basic".
Instalar el complemento 'JsonConverter': Si necesitas trabajar con datos JSON esto viene de maravilla:
https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON
(no especificas si tu api responde con un json, si no es así, deberás manejar la respuesta de otra forma).
Agregas un nuevo módulo y te dejo el siguiente ejemplo (Es algo bastante basico).
Sub EnviarSolicitudPOST()

    ' Crear un objeto para la solicitud HTTP
    Dim WinHttpReq As Object
    Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

    ' Definir la URL de la API <-- aqui pones la ruta de tu peticion
    Dim URL As String
    URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"

    ' Configurar la solicitud POST
    WinHttpReq.Open "POST", URL, False
    WinHttpReq.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"

    ' Preparar los datos para enviar en formato JSON
    Dim postData As String
    postData = "{""title"": ""Aprendiendo VBA"", ""body"": ""Este es un ejemplo de solicitud POST"", ""userId"": 1}"

    ' Enviar la solicitud
    WinHttpReq.Send postData

    ' Capturar la respuesta
    Dim jsonResponse As String
    jsonResponse = WinHttpReq.ResponseText

    ' Convertir la respuesta JSON en un objeto (esto requiere JsonConverter)
    Dim json As Object
    Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(jsonResponse)

    ' Escribir la respuesta en la hoja de Excel
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    ' Encabezados en la primera fila
    ws.Cells(1, 1).Value = "ID"
    ws.Cells(1, 2).Value = "Título"
    ws.Cells(1, 3).Value = "Cuerpo"
    ws.Cells(1, 4).Value = "ID Usuario"

    ' Datos en la segunda fila
    ws.Cells(2, 1).Value = json("id")
    ws.Cells(2, 2).Value = json("title")
    ws.Cells(2, 3).Value = json("body")
    ws.Cells(2, 4).Value = json("userId")

    End Sub

Con esto podrás manipular tu respuesta. espero te sirva!!
